# Statement returning an empty string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am confused as to why when I make an ajax call to my php script, it returns an empty string. I believe I am checking for this in php and if empty should trigger the notif msg. It is constantly triggering the success msg even if the string is coming back empty. In the post section of firebug, I can see that all the inputs are being posted with correct values and if I alert the serialize data, that is also being posted correctly.

How can I check if php is receiving the data? I have tried print_r, var_dump but nothing is displayed in the console. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

jQuery

```
$(function() {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'span',
        ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.siblings('span'));
        }
    });

$("#USRrecycle").validate({
rules: {
    rcyrequested: {
        required: true
    },
    rcyservice: {
        required: true
    },
    rcydept: {
        required: true
    },
    rcyaddress: {
        required: true
    },
    rcyqty: {
        required: true,
        number: true
    },
    rcydatepicker: {
        required: true,
        date: true
    }

},
messages: {
    rcyrequested: {
        required: '* required: You must enter your name'
    },
    rcydept: {
        required: "* required: You must select a department"
    },
    rcyaddress: {
        required: "* required: You must select a customer address"
    },
    rcyservice: {
        required: "* required: You must select a service level"
    },
    rcyqty: {
        required: "* required: You must enter a quantity",
        number: "* Quantity amount must be a number. ie, 200"
    },
    rcydatepicker: {
        required: "* required: You must enter a delivery recycle date",
        date: "* You must enter a date only in this format: 07/10/2014"
    }
},

submitHandler: function() {

            if ($("#USRrecycle").valid() === true) {
                var data = $("#USRrecycle").serialize();
                alert(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "rcy.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {


                        if (data.opp == 'error') {
                         console.log(data.qty);

                            notif({
                                msg: '<br />ERROR! ' + '<b><font color="red">' + data.qty + '</font></b>' + ' was NOT SUBMITTED.<br /><br /> You must enter an amout.<br /><br />' + 'Please correct this error and try again.' + 'Thank you.',
                                type: "boxDstrError",
                                position: "center",
                                width: 490,
                                height: 75,
                                multiline: true,
                                timeout: 8000,
                                opacity: 0.8,
                                fade: 10,
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log(data.qty);
                            $("#USRrecycle").get(0).reset();
                            $("#rcydept").trigger("chosen:updated");
                            $("#rcyaddress").trigger("chosen:updated");

                            notif({
                                msg: "Your submission was successfull."  + '<br /><br />' + '<b><font color=\"black\">' + data.qty + '</font></b><br /><br />' + ' This entry was successfully submitted to the database.<br />Thank you.',
                                type: "boxdstrSuccess",
                                position: "center",
                                width: 490,
                                height: 75,
                                multiline: true,
                                timeout: 8000,
                                opacity: 0.8,
                                fade: 10,
                            });
                          }
                       }
                   });
                }
            }

       });
});
```

php - rcy.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

  // test vars from jquery form
  $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
  $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr']);
  $requested = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcyrequested']);
  $activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcyactivity']);
  $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcyaddress']);
  $service = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcyservice']);
  $date = explode('/', $_POST['rcydatepicker']);
  $newdate = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
  $authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['kt_name_usr']);
  $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcydept']);

    $array = array();
    $array = $_POST['rcyqty'];

    $outString = ''; 


    foreach ($array as $qty) {
        $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($qty);

        // If $qty is empty, send output to outstring to display notif error msg
        if ($qty == " ") {

            $outString .= $qty . ' ';

    }   
    }
    if ($outString) { // if there are numbers in this string, then there are error Duplicates
        $error = array('opp' => "error", 'qty' => $outString); // qty will have the TEXT for notif msg
    // IMPORTANT, have changed JSON output to use an Opperation (opp) to indicate
    // in javascript if there was an error OR not
        $output = json_encode($error);
        echo $output;
        exit();
    }


    // Will Only execute the SUCCESS if $outString is empty (no exit();)

    foreach ($array as $qty) {
        $outString .= $qty . ' ';

        $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($qty);

    }

    $json = array('opp' => 'insert', 'qty' => $outString);
    $result = json_encode($json);
    echo $result;
?>
```

html

```
<div class="fieldset">
   <h1><span>Enter Quantity Reqd</span></h1>
      <p>
         <input id="rcyqty" name="rcyqty" type="text" required="required" style="width:250px; height:30px;" /><span></span>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="removeclass"></a>
         <a style="margin-left: 14px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="Please enter the quantity of boxes/sacks that you require.">Help</a>
      </p>
</div>
```

Comment: check the browser network tab to see what data is sent

Comment: @Arun As far as I can see in the net tab of firebug, all data is being posted correctly. However, in the html tab, this is what is reported. {"opp":"insert","qty":""} Thanks

Comment: after " success: function(data) { " add "console.log(data);" and see what you are getting as response. Perhaps that's not satisfying your if-else.

Comment: is **success** is called after the ajax request ? put an alert or debug it

Comment: that is the response... check the request parameters... if you are using chrome it will be listed in the `Headers` tab in the network panel

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but going to find an alternative way of dealing with this. json not reqd with this part of the interface.